# Performance data analysis in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, analysis

Are there any tools on the market that effectively analyze data in SharePoint lists? I have a client looking to analyze and report on employee performance data stored in SharePoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Does SSRS give you anything useful](http://www.sharepointblogs.com/dwise/archive/2007/11/28/connecting-sql-reporting-services-to-a-sharepoint-list-redux.aspx)?

Do you just need to report the data, or do you require complicated aggregation?

Comment: The requirements are still coming in, but it appears we'll require complex aggregation

Answer (score 1):

Nintex reports on SharePoint itself (and is acually quite cheap). The way the question is stated the report might be about employee data in a sharepoint list so SSRS does make more sense.

You can also look at some the BI features that come with MOSS Enterprise such as the KPI web part, scorecards, reports, Excel services and dashboards.

Comment: Yes the data is in multiple lists. and it needs to be aggregated and presented.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to SSRS you should also consider using either Excel or Access to run reports :-

[Analysing SharePoint Data in Excel](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2009.02.bookbi.aspx#id0060016)
(Look for the section titled SharePoint-to-Excel and Data Synchronization)

[How to Link SharePoint Server 2007 Lists with Microsoft Access 2007](http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/_layouts/error.aspx?aspxerrorpath=/blogs/GetThePoint/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx)

Page currently borked, cached version http://209.85.229.132/search?q=cache:YnuTwWha77UJ:sharepoint.microsoft.com/blogs/GetThePoint/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx%3FID%3D68+connecting+access+to+sharepoint+lists&cd=5&hl=en&ct=clnk

Remember that you can also access the list data as XML so any 3rd party BI/reporting tool that can call one of [SharePoints web services](http://www.csharphelp.com/archives4/archive602.html) and manipulate the resulting XML could also be used - there are must be hundreds of contenders here.

The best tool to use depends upon many factors such as what you may be familiar with, the complexity of analysis you need, if you need static or dynamic reports (drill down etc). BI & Reporting tools are a *huge* area!

Finally if you need fairly simple PivotTable/crosstab type functionality then this [CrossTab web part](http://www.pentalogic.net/crosstab-for-sharepoint.aspx) may be suitable (*disclaimer - its sold by my company*)